# Are functions of independent random variables related to each other by a constant independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have $6$ random variables $a,b,c,d,f,g$, each having independent Gaussian distribution. Now I define following three random variables
\begin{equation}
X = ab - cd\\
Y = cf - ag\\
Z = gd - bf
\end{equation}
where, $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=\text{constant}$. The value of the constant is not known to me. Can I say that the distributions of $X,Y,Z$ are independent of each other?

Comment: In what sense is $X^2+Y^2+Z^2$ an unknown constant?

Comment: You can assume that $X^2+Y^2+Z^2 = R^2$ describes the equation of a sphere, whose radius, $R$, is not known to me.